# MYSQL - Compare 2 Arrays

Tags: mysql

I would like to update my MYSQL query conditions to also include the equivalent of "AND all of the numbers in array 1 are present in array 2".

```
Array1: (1,14,7)
Array2: (1,23,45,14,6)
```

So, this example would fail because "7" is not present. If I use "IN" it would require that they match in the same order? or can you compare using that?

Can I do this as part of the MYSQL Query or do I need to get the results first and then loop through them throwing out some that don't match??

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays, so your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: You could replace "array" with "table" and then your question would be answerable.

Comment: Sorry about the terminology guys - MYSQL really isn't my thing - lol. I know I can use a variable that contains a comma seperated list of values for an IN check (e.g "IF 5 IN ($val)" - where $val = 1,2,3,4 - but I assume the expression being compared can't also be a variable containing a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order does not matter.
you can use this condition

```
WHERE SomeColumn IN (1,14,7) AND SomeColumn IN (1,23,45,14,6)
```

This is will give you the intersection between both sets, which are 1 & 14 only

Comment: Excellent - we're getting warmer. The condition needs to be "if ALL of these numbers (1st list) are contained within those numbers (2nd list)". Both lists are an array of numbers. If it can't be done in MYSQL I can easily just get the rows and then use a loop to remove those that don't qualify - am just trying to make it all quicker by disqualifying them earlier.